# gcd and lcm of $a$ and$ $b in $\mathbb Z$ which verify...

Tags: discrete-mathematics

$\DeclareMathOperator{\lcm}{lcm}$$\DeclareMathOperator{\mcd}{mcd}$Found all couples $a,b$ in $\mathbb Z$ which verify $\gcd(a,b)=10$ and $\lcm(a,b)=100$.

I've tried to decompose $a$ and $p$ in prime numbers and I've taken the property $\gcd(a,b)\cdot \lcm(a,b)=a\cdot b$ but when I've done that, I only found one solution which is $a=b=5^2\, 2^2$.

Comment: mcd = "máximo común divisor" = "greatest common divisor" = gcd in English

Comment: mcm = "mínimo común múltiplo" = "lowest common multiple" = lcm in English

Comment: If $a=b$ then the $\gcd (a,b)=a$.

Comment: Hint:  write $a=10A,b=10B$ where $\gcd(A,B)=1$.  What can you say about $AB$?

Comment: Oh ok I've just seen it. I'd answer that solutions are: a=5*2, 5²*2,5*2²,5²*2² and b=5²*2²,5*2²,5²*2,5*2 (a1 corresponda with b1...)

Answer (score 1):

$$\gcd(a,b)=10\to a=10m,b=10n,\gcd(m,n)=1\\ lcm(a,b)=lcm(10m,10n)=10mn=100\to mn=10$$
since $\gcd(m,n)=1$ we have different cases:

Case 1:

$m=1,n=10 \quad \to\quad a=10,b=100$

Case 2:

$m=2,n=5 \quad \to\quad a=20,b=50$

Case 3:

$m=5,n=2 \quad \to\quad a=50,b=20$

Case 4:

$m=10,n=1 \quad \to\quad a=100,b=10$